# Linux thread execution flow

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am using pthread in Linux and I have implemented two classes (which inherit from another class which abstracts POSIX threads) running as threads. Thread1 is starting and stopping thread2. During thread2 is running, thread1 is calling a function of the thread2 class. My question is when thread1 is calling this function, when is it executed? is it executed just in time as it is called so that thread2 perform the operation of this method and continues afterwards where it stopped?

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. Thread in pthread is not a class. There are no classes in pthread. Post code and explain slowly and accurately what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse **classes** and **threads**. Classes and threads are independent and unrelated concepts. Executing code from a different *class* will not cause that code to be run in a different *thread*. Any method called on thread X will run on thread X.

Comment: If there are two methods for example. One method is running indefinitely (e.g. run()) and the other method is called by other thread. My question is that when the second method is called by other thread when is it executed? Since thread1 is continuously executing the first method, does it stop executing it and start executing the second method and when it is completed, it continues where it stopped in the first method.

Comment: Apply my last sentence: "Any method called on thread X will run on thread X." When you call a method from the other thread it will run on the other thread. The first thread will know nothing about this method invocation; it doesn't matter what *class* the method belongs to. Classes and threads are independent and unrelated concepts.

Comment: Sure it will run on thread X. But will it run just in time it is called?

Comment: Yes, it will run immediately, in the current thread, like any other function call.

Answer (score 1):

Threads execute callables which are in your case probably member functions. If you encapsulate a phtread in a class, only the corresponding member function becomes parallel, other calls to other member function would still run on the caller thread.